# Move a window back into the visible area in Xubuntu?

Tags: external-display, window-manager, xfce, xubuntu

On my laptop, after I use a higher-resolution external monitor, applications will sometimes place themselves outside the visible area of my desktop. How do I move them back into the visible area?
(No part of the window is visible, so I can't use the mouse.)

I'm running Xubuntu 9.10 (XFCE)

Comment: is this the latest Xubuntu (10.04)? or some earlier version?

Comment: No it was the 9.10, I have not updated that laptop. Shortly after I wrote the question I happen to find the answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it, I'm answering just in case someone else get confused.

Under: 
settings -> Window manager -> Keyboard

There is shortcut called "Move window"

And if I first cykle the app into focus with Alt+tab and then Alt+F7 (the move window), the app jumps to the mouse pointer and then I could just place it where I wanted it..

Comment: For anyone else finding this, I had to focus the window (Alt+Tab), press and hold down Alt+F7 which then allowed me then to click and drag the window. I.e. for me it didn't jump to the mouse cursor and pressing Alt+F7.